# How to parse this string to extract the email?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to use Ruby code in IRB to extract emails from a long list of emails. Here's the format:

boogieshooz@hotmail.com:6c86ba58f135f43b54e33954934e00b8
booking@abandontheory.com:6c86ba58f135f43b54e33954934e00b8

I have a list like this of thousands and I want to remove the second half of the string and just extract the email. How can I achieve this?

I have tried this:

```
 input.split('.').select do |email| 
   email.downcase.include?('@')
 end
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, input.split('.').select do |email|
  email.downcase.include?('@')
end.

Comment: and what's your problem? It is not working or what?

Comment: doesn't work for an array

Answer (score 1):

How about using `split`?

```
"boogieshooz@hotmail.com:6c86ba58f135f43b54e33954934e00b8".split(':')[0]
```

Edit: if emails are in an `Array`

```
emails.map { |email| email.split(':')[0] }
```

Comment: what if I have 500 emails in an "emails" array? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks kcdragon, almost there - issue now is it only captures the first email address. We need to capture all. The array was setup as such, emails = ["Carlota@Carlotasantacruz.com:1ba6be96f0641665bbcc080d0e47db33
carmenlang@arteven.net:ab85f491d0bc4fbdfa552f1082844234
carol.glad@att.net:5f3975d5405d65b3e9f7ef2032b46ed7
carol.levow@gmail.com:3002bc92d52b30252295a1f859afcdab
carol@winterstreetdesign.com:ef41565edff017f3dae9eaff92df7112
carolechilcote@hotmail.com:491c29c84feb88ca3a65c5757921613e
carolinalugo1@msn.com:92e5db41232a745819ae520144eb8b22"]

Comment: I think your Array is setup wrong them. It looks like you have an Array with a single String instead of an Array with a String for each line. Can you post the code you wrote to generate that Array?

Answer (score 0):

If the emails are stored in a single String you can use a regular expression in order to retrieve all emails.

Something like:

```
address = mails.scan(/(.*@.*?)\:/)
```

where **mails** is the String.